# Webjob V3 not starting: Method not found: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a V3 .NET webjob that isn't starting on my local machine. I haven't worked on it for a while but I have gone through several rounds of package updates since then when updating packages across the solution. (Without testing the webjob, yes I know, stupid of me.)

Here is the output from the webjob console:

`fail: Host.Startup[0] The listener for function 'Functions.Run' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The listener for function 'Functions.Run' was unable to start. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DistributedLockManagerContainerProvider.get_InternalContainer()'. at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.get_TimerStatusDirectory() at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.GetStatusBlobReference(String timerName) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Scheduling\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 144 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.<GetStatusAsync>d__10.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Listeners.TimerListener.<StartAsync>d__27.MoveNext() in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Listener\TimerListener.cs:line 99 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.SingletonListener.<StartAsync>d__13.MoveNext() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Singleton\SingletonListener.cs:line 70 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.<StartAsync>d__13.MoveNext() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs:line 68 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---`

The error is occurring here:

```
IHost host = builder.Build();  

using (host)
{
    Run(); // Exception
```

I've tried a bunch of different things but I'm not even sure what this error message means. I think it might be either the storage emulator or the new packages but I'm not sure.

Comment: Could you please provide your sdk version?

Comment: @JimXu According to this path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK` I have versions 2.4 to 2.9 installed. Is this right place to look?

Comment: Hi. I want to know you use which packages in your webjob project.

Comment: @JimXu Of course, sorry. Here is the packages file: https://pastebin.pl/view/fec57361

Comment: @JimXu do you have any ideas what the problem might be? I'm really stuck on this one.

Comment: Is that you use timmer trigger in your web job?

Comment: @JimXu yes, I'm using a timer trigger to run the webjob on a CRON schedule.

Comment: According to my test, it is ok for me with webjob sdk v3. My package file : https://pastebin.pl/view/49b56a88. My `Program.cs` is : https://pastebin.pl/view/bce541fe

Comment: @JimXu Thank you! May I see your Functions.cs file also?

Comment: My function file: https://pastebin.pl/view/cee1dbd2. My result: https://ibb.co/vcgtQH1

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know exactly what went wrong, but obviously package upgrades broke something.  The new webjob project template has a different structure than the old one I was using and having problems with.

For example, in Visual Studio, instead of Properties, References, and packages.config the new project has Dependencies, under which are Assemblies, Packages, and Projects. Also, when you double click the new project name in Visual Studio it opens the .csproj file.

I transferred the logic from the old webjob project into a new one which obviously uses the latest webjob template. You also can configure storage strings a bit differently in the new template, for example `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsDashboard",` and `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage",`

My webjob is working now and moving the logic into the new project didn't take long.